# How can I make selenium 'find_element' not be static?

Tags: python, selenium

I don't know If I expressed myself right, but my problem is I have this code:

```
def select_chat():
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    while True:
        chat_unread = driver.find_element_by_class_name('chat-drag-cover')
        chat_contains = chat_unread.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        if 'chat_unread' in chat_contains:
            chat_unread.click()

select_chat()
```

So this function should find multiple elements which contain 'chat unread', the problem is it does find the elements but it locks on one of them and doesn't go for the others, what can I do?

Comment: And I don't see where do you break the while loop, I assume you do that somewhere.
I would use this 

  `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )`

Comment: The problem is: there is multiple 'divs' containing 'chat unread', after detecting one 'find_element' doesn't find the others so the driver can click on them, because of that the driver only clicks on the first one detected, I'm trying to make it click in multiple unread chats one time after the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets have a look at whats happening in your code :

When you `find_element_by_class_name('chat-drag-cover')` the very first match (which is an `WebElement`) is returned and gets stored within `chat_unread`. 
Example:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="11a81cb13625b168f875de3b10dca3c5", element="0.3018415455432639-1")>
```

Next we are retriving the `'innerHTML'` and storing it in `chat_contains` (which is a `String`). 
Example:

```
Explore the life and work
```

Finally, we are trying to verify `if 'chat_unread' in chat_contains:`. Which is equivalent to :

If the String **`<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="11a81cb13625b168f875de3b10dca3c5", element="0.3018415455432639-1")>`**

contains

**`Explore the life and work`** which is always **False**.

So `click()` is never called and we get back again to `driver.find_element_by_class_name`.

So the solution would be to use `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("foo")` which returns a list as follows :

```
chat_unread = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('chat-drag-cover')
```

Lastly, the **`WebElement`** itself e.g. **`chat unread`** must not be part of any validation but it's attributes should be used e.g. **`innerHTML`**

Comment: Well the strangest thing is that it actually click in one of the elements containing 'chat unread', but it doesnt click in all of them...

Comment: IMO, the `IDE` or `Python Interpreter ` should complain that we are trying to stack up an `WebElement` against a `String`

Comment: Fixed by changing find_element_by_class_name to find_element_by_css_selector, but thank you :)